# Unable to login to my joomla backend

Tags: joomla, authentication, backend

anyone can help me please!

it is about joomla control panel backend, I don't know why I can't login, every time I try to access it is just send me back to the same login page..

The site frontend is working fine,  and the backend is working fine on my localhost.

Comment: Not a question for [so]. You may get help on [su]

Comment: Well for starters there is a red error messaging starring you in the face: `Error - Your host needs to disable magic_quotes_gpc to run this version of Joomla!`. I have just tried to login with the details you provided and it works fine for me. I've flagged the question to be removed as you're posing a security threat to your site by providing user credentials

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to login and it was fine.
There are two things you need to do for your Joomla site:

1. Error: Your host needs to disable magic_quotes_gpc to run this version of Joomla! => ask your hosting provider to disable magic_quotes_gpc
2. Update your Joomla from Joomla 3.1.6 to Joomla 3.2.1 as soon as possible.